# Open a Site as a Window in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm not certain if this is a valid question for this particular site, but I am using the Google Maps API v.3, and I was wondering about a feature.  I'm not sure if this is possible given the restrictions Google has on the HTML that it will interpret in an info-window, but I would like to be able to open a new web site in an infoWindow (or something similar to it).  The application is a bit involved, but the basics are that I am trying to integrate the information from one site, which I can't actually access, with the data I display in my map.  As a temporary fix, I'd like to simply open the secondary website in a window on the map and let the user sign in as normal.  Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: What about an iframe inside the infoWindow?